# What's the difference between grid-column value 1/1 and 1/2?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

In CSS grid, `grid-column: 1/1` and `1/2` are showing the same result. Is there any difference between them? Look at the code below.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

.item1 {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
  <div class="item3">3</div>
  <div class="item4">4</div>
  <div class="item5">5</div>
  <div class="item6">6</div>
  <div class="item7">7</div>
</div>
```

`grid-column` value `1 / 2` and  `1 / 1` is same. What's the difference?

Comment: Question: What are you trying to arrive at?

It is because you are spanning one track from by using the grid-column value 1 / 2 and 1 / 1.

Comment: You understand right what I'm trying to say here, for 1/2(starting line) - that's why box will span till 2 but for 1/1(starting line) - then why it also spans till 2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because of a misunderstanding of what `grid-column: 1 / 2` means.

It does NOT mean span two columns (the First & Second)...it means that the element **starts** at grid-**line** 1 and ends at grid-**line** 2.

[**Grid Track @ MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Grid_Tracks)

> A grid track is the space between **two grid line**s. They are defined in the explicit grid by using the grid-template-columns and grid-template-rows properties or the shorthand grid or grid-template properties. Tracks are also created in the implicit grid by positioning a grid Item outside of the tracks created in the explicit grid.

So in your example, because you have 4 columns, there are 5 **explicit** *grid-lines* (I'll exclude any grid-lines created by the implict grid to avoid confusion).

Since the first column will always be between lines 1 & 2, it spans only the first column.

- Column 1 : Lines 1 - 2
- Column 2 : Lines 2 - 3
- Column 3 : Lines 3 - 4
- Column 4 : Lines 4 - 5

`grid-column: 1/1` is essentially *invalid* so it resets to it's default which is to span only the first column.

[A Complete Guide to Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

Comment: Thanks for the last line - `grid-column: 1/1 is essentially invalid so it resets to its default which is to span only the first column`. This is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is explained in the Grid spec:

> [**8.3.1. Grid Placement Conflict
>   Handling**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#grid-placement-errors)
>
> If the start line is equal to the end line, remove the end line.

Okay, so what happens when the end line is removed?

It computes to `auto`.

> [**8.4. Placement Shorthands: the `grid-column`, `grid-row`, and `grid-area`
>   properties**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#placement-shorthands)
>
> If two `<grid-line>` values are specified, the `grid-row-start` /
>   `grid-column-start` longhand is set to the value before the slash, and
>   the `grid-row-end` / `grid-column-end` longhand is set to the value
>   after the slash.
>
> When the second value is omitted, if the first value is a
>   `<custom-ident>`, the `grid-row-end` / `grid-column-end` longhand is
>   also set to that `<custom-ident>`; otherwise, it is set to `auto`.

The value [**`auto`** means `span 1`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#grid-placement-auto).

A [`<custom-ident>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#custom-idents) is an author-defined identifier and, in Grid, refers to [named grid areas](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#named-lines), like this:

```
#grid {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: [first nav-start] 150px [main-start] 1fr [last];
 grid-template-rows: [first header-start] 50px [main-start] 1fr [footer-start] 50px [last];
}
```

Since there are no named grid areas in your code, the `grid-column` end line resolves to `auto`.

Therefore, the following rules are all the same:

- `grid-column: 1 / 2`
- `grid-column: 1 / 1`
- `grid-column: 1 / auto`
- `grid-column: 1`