# What is grid-column : 1 / -1 meaning

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to grid. can any one explain what is 1 / -1 mean.

```
 <style>
  .parrent {
     display: grid;
     grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
     grid-column-gap: 3.5rem;
     grid-row-gap: var(--space-20);
   }
   .third {
     grid-column: 1/-1;
     justify-content: center;
    }
 </style>
 <div class="parrent"> 
    <div>First </div>
    <div>Second</div>
    <div class="third">Third</div>
 </div>
```

what is that third column grid-column : 1/-1 meaning

Comment: Look at this post, you'll find your answer : https://stackoverflow.com/q/49005233/12348877